# Troubles with using hook useState()

Tags: reactjs

Trying to use `fetched data` into hook `useState(fetchedData)`

```
const [car, setCar] = useState({images: []});

useEffect( () => {
        fetchOneCar(id)
            .then(data => setCar(data))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    },[id]);

 const [images,setImages] = useState(car.images)

 console.log(images) // -> [] unpredictably empty
 console.log(car.images) // -> [{},{},{}] (fetched data)
```

How to **properly** set data into useState() in my case ?

Comment: Does `data` contains `images`? if so, then why don't you set it inside the `then` call?

Comment: Why do you have a separate `images` state atom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok look first car is `{images:[]}`
then images is `[]`
and then car turns into whatever data you fetched in use effect
just because you declare `useState` after use effect doesn't mean it will run after `useEffect`.
First all the `useStates` run and then the effects. that's the law.
so there is no unexpected result.
To fix this in yur use effect do this:

```
useEffect( () => {
        fetchOneCar(id)
            .then(data => {
             setCar(data);
             setImages(data)
             })
            .finally(() => setLoading(false))
},[id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, I expect that you want to fill the `images` with the result from `data`. If it is, then you have to put the `setImages(data.images)` inside the resolved promise, after the `setCar(data)`.
It should be like this one

```
const [car, setCar] = useState({images: []});
const [images,setImages] = useState();
useEffect( () => {
    fetchOneCar(id)
        .then(data => {
              setCar(data);
              setImages(data.images);
         })
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))
},[id]);
```

I put the `useState()` for `images` at the top for better reading.